# Error in Guile Procedure "procedure->pointer": Wrong Type Argument in Position 1

Tags: c, scheme, guile

So the Guile procedure "procedure->pointer" takes a return type, Scheme function, and a list of parameter types, and returns a C function pointer.

procedure->pointer: (return type, Scheme function, list of parameter types) -> C function pointer

My question is, if I define a custom type "foo" in C (either through a typedef or a struct definition), how do I register it in Guile such that I can use "foo" as a return type or parameter type in procedure->pointer? Would I be passing procedure->pointer a symbol called "foo," or a Scheme variable called "foo?"

Edit: I would like to call something like:

```
foo (*c_foo_func)(foo) = scm_procedure_to_pointer(foo, scm_foo_func, scm_list_1(foo));
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add relevant code to your question.

Comment: Sure, here it is.

Comment: From discussion in comments: OP is trying to call [H5Literate](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5L.html#Link-Iterate) from [HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/). This requires passing a Scheme procedure to a C function. One of the arguments to the Scheme procedure is a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### C typedef declarations

In C, `typedef` declarations create synonyms, not new types. Look up
the declarations to discover the real type. For example, the signature
of `H5Fclose` is

```
herr_t H5Fclose(hid_t file_id);
```

The types `herr_t` and `hid_t` are declared in the HDF5 header files as

```
typedef int herr_t;
typedef int hid_t;
```

So to create a Scheme procedure that wraps `H5Fclose`, use

```lisp
(pointer->procedure int (dynamic-func "H5Fclose" ...) (list int))
```

Alternatively, the same synonyms can be defined in Scheme:

```lisp
(define herr_t int)
(define hid_t int)
```

Then you can write

```lisp
(pointer->procedure herr_t (dynamic-func "H5Fclose" ...) (list hid_t))
```

### Passing structs by pointer

In C, structs are usually passed to and from functions by pointer. For
example, the signature of callbacks passed to
[H5Literate](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5L.html#Link-Iterate)
is

```
herr_t op(hid_t group, const char *name, const H5L_info_t *info, void *op_data);
```

`H5L_info_t` is a struct type which is passed by pointer.

The representation of the callback's argument types in Scheme is

```lisp
(list int '* '* '*)
```

The functions `make-c-struct` and `parse-c-struct`
([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Foreign-Structs.html))
create and read struct pointers. They need to know the layout of the
struct, which is given as a list with the types of the struct members.

### Passing structs by value

Guile also supports passing structs by value, though it isn't
documented. The functions `pointer->procedure` and
`procedure->pointer`
([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Dynamic-FFI.html))
take the return and argument types. To denote a struct that is passed
by value, use a list with the types of the struct members.

Manipulation of the struct values in Scheme is still done using
`make-c-struct` and `parse-c-struct` (the struct values are
automatically converted to pointers and back).

### Example

The following example demonstrates how to pass a Scheme procedure to
the C function `H5Literate`. It is a translation of "Iterate over
Groups w/ H5Literate" from the [HDF5 C
Examples](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/examples/api18-c.html).

The sample data file
[h5ex_g_iterate.h5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/files/exbyapi/h5ex_g_iterate.h5)
needs to be in the working directory.

A lot of code is required to replicate the types and constants from
the HDF5 headers, but the actual program is quite short (it's at the
very end).

```lisp
(use-modules
 (system foreign)
 (rnrs bytevectors))

(define libhdf5 (dynamic-link "libhdf5"))

;; HDF5 typedefs

;; typedef int herr_t;
(define herr_t int)
;; typedef int hid_t;
(define hid_t int)

;; typedef enum H5_index_t {
;;     H5_INDEX_UNKNOWN = -1,      /* Unknown index type                   */
;;     H5_INDEX_NAME,              /* Index on names                       */
;;     H5_INDEX_CRT_ORDER,         /* Index on creation order              */
;;     H5_INDEX_N                  /* Number of indices defined            */
;; } H5_index_t;
(define H5_index_t int)
(define H5_INDEX_NAME 0)

;; typedef enum {
;;     H5_ITER_UNKNOWN = -1,       /* Unknown order */
;;     H5_ITER_INC,                /* Increasing order */
;;     H5_ITER_DEC,                /* Decreasing order */
;;     H5_ITER_NATIVE,             /* No particular order, whatever is fastest */
;;     H5_ITER_N                   /* Number of iteration orders */
;; } H5_iter_order_t;
(define H5_iter_order_t int)
(define H5_ITER_NATIVE 2)

;; typedef herr_t (*H5L_iterate_t)(hid_t group, const char *name, const H5L_info_t *info,
;;     void *op_data);
(define H5L_iterate_t '*)

;; typedef uint64_t haddr_t;
(define haddr_t uint64)

;; typedef enum H5O_type_t {
;;     H5O_TYPE_UNKNOWN = -1,      /* Unknown object type          */
;;     H5O_TYPE_GROUP,             /* Object is a group            */
;;     H5O_TYPE_DATASET,           /* Object is a dataset          */
;;     H5O_TYPE_NAMED_DATATYPE,    /* Object is a named data type  */
;;     H5O_TYPE_NTYPES             /* Number of different object types (must be last!) */
;; } H5O_type_t;
(define H5O_type_t int)
(define H5O_TYPE_GROUP 0)
(define H5O_TYPE_DATASET 1)
(define H5O_TYPE_NAMED_DATATYPE 2)

;; time_t is long on POSIX systems
(define time_t long)

;; typedef unsigned long long      hsize_t;
;; (system foreign) doesn't have long long, use uint64 and cross our fingers
(define hsize_t uint64)

;; typedef struct H5O_hdr_info_t {
;;     unsigned version;           /* Version number of header format in file */
;;     unsigned nmesgs;            /* Number of object header messages */
;;     unsigned nchunks;           /* Number of object header chunks */
;;     unsigned flags;             /* Object header status flags */
;;     struct {
;;         hsize_t total;          /* Total space for storing object header in file */
;;         hsize_t meta;           /* Space within header for object header metadata information */
;;         hsize_t mesg;           /* Space within header for actual message information */
;;         hsize_t free;           /* Free space within object header */
;;     } space;
;;     struct {
;;         uint64_t present;       /* Flags to indicate presence of message type in header */
;;         uint64_t shared;        /* Flags to indicate message type is shared in header */
;;     } mesg;
;; } H5O_hdr_info_t;
(define H5O_hdr_info_t
  (list
   unsigned-int
   unsigned-int
   unsigned-int
   unsigned-int
   (list
    hsize_t
    hsize_t
    hsize_t
    hsize_t)
   (list
    uint64
    uint64)))

;; typedef struct H5_ih_info_t {
;;     hsize_t     index_size;     /* btree and/or list */
;;     hsize_t     heap_size;
;; } H5_ih_info_t;
(define H5_ih_info_t
  (list
   hsize_t
   hsize_t))

;; typedef struct H5O_info_t {
;;     unsigned long       fileno;         /* File number that object is located in */
;;     haddr_t             addr;           /* Object address in file       */
;;     H5O_type_t          type;           /* Basic object type (group, dataset, etc.) */
;;     unsigned            rc;             /* Reference count of object    */
;;     time_t              atime;          /* Access time                  */
;;     time_t              mtime;          /* Modification time            */
;;     time_t              ctime;          /* Change time                  */
;;     time_t              btime;          /* Birth time                   */
;;     hsize_t             num_attrs;      /* # of attributes attached to object */
;;     H5O_hdr_info_t      hdr;            /* Object header information */
;;     /* Extra metadata storage for obj & attributes */
;;     struct {
;;         H5_ih_info_t   obj;             /* v1/v2 B-tree & local/fractal heap for groups, B-tree for chunked datasets */
;;         H5_ih_info_t   attr;            /* v2 B-tree & heap for attributes */
;;     } meta_size;
;; } H5O_info_t;
(define H5O_info_t
  (list
   unsigned-long
   haddr_t
   H5O_type_t
   unsigned-int
   time_t
   time_t
   time_t
   time_t
   hsize_t
   H5O_hdr_info_t
   (list
    H5_ih_info_t
    H5_ih_info_t)))
(define (make-H5O_info_t)
  "Returns a pointer to a zero-initialized H50_info_t struct."
  (bytevector->pointer (make-bytevector (sizeof H5O_info_t) 0)))
(define (parse-H5O_info_t foreign)
  (parse-c-struct foreign H5O_info_t))
(define (H5O_info_t-type vals)
  (list-ref vals 2))

;; HDF5 constants

;; #define H5F_ACC_RDONLY  (H5CHECK 0x0000u)
(define H5F_ACC_RDONLY 0)

;; #define H5P_DEFAULT     (hid_t)0
(define H5P_DEFAULT 0)

;; HDF5 functions

;; hid_t
;; H5Fopen(const char *filename, unsigned flags, hid_t fapl_id);
(define H5Fopen
  (pointer->procedure
   hid_t
   (dynamic-func "H5Fopen" libhdf5)
   (list '* unsigned-int hid_t)))

;; herr_t
;; H5Literate(hid_t grp_id, H5_index_t idx_type, H5_iter_order_t order,
;;     hsize_t *idx_p, H5L_iterate_t op, void *op_data);
(define H5Literate
  (pointer->procedure
   herr_t
   (dynamic-func "H5Literate" libhdf5)
   (list hid_t H5_index_t H5_iter_order_t '* H5L_iterate_t '*)))

;; herr_t
;; H5Fclose(hid_t file_id);
(define H5Fclose
  (pointer->procedure
   herr_t
   (dynamic-func "H5Fclose" libhdf5)
   (list hid_t)))

;; herr_t
;; H5Oget_info_by_name(hid_t loc_id, const char *name, H5O_info_t *oinfo, hid_t lapl_id);
(define H5Oget_info_by_name
  (pointer->procedure
   herr_t
   (dynamic-func "H5Oget_info_by_name" libhdf5)
   (list hid_t '* '* hid_t)))

(define FILE "h5ex_g_iterate.h5")

(define (main)
  (let ((status 0)
        (file (H5Fopen (string->pointer FILE) H5F_ACC_RDONLY H5P_DEFAULT)))
    (display "Objects in root group:\n")
    (set! status (H5Literate file H5_INDEX_NAME H5_ITER_NATIVE %null-pointer
                             op_func_ptr %null-pointer))
    (set! status (H5Fclose file))
    0))

;; Operator function. Prints the name and type of the object
;; being examined.
;;
;; C signature:
;; herr_t op_func (hid_t loc_id, const char *name, const H5L_info_t *info,
;;             void *operator_data)
(define (op_func loc_id name info operator_data)
  (let ((status 0)
        (name-str (pointer->string name))
        (infobuf (make-H5O_info_t)))
    (set! status (H5Oget_info_by_name loc_id name infobuf H5P_DEFAULT))
    (let ((type (H5O_info_t-type (parse-H5O_info_t infobuf))))
      (cond
       ((= type H5O_TYPE_GROUP)
        (format #t "  Group: ~a\n" name-str))
       ((= type H5O_TYPE_DATASET)
        (format #t "  Dataset: ~a\n" name-str))
       ((= type H5O_TYPE_NAMED_DATATYPE)
        (format #t "  Datatype: ~a\n" name-str))
       (else
        (format #t "  Unknown: ~a\n" name-str))))
    0))

(define op_func_ptr (procedure->pointer herr_t op_func (list hid_t '* '* '*)))

(main)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that my function pointers must conform to a pre-defined function declaration. I am not sure replacing an type with a pointer of that type is a legal solution, because I am passing the function pointer as an argument to another function from a C library (libhdf5).

Comment: @MoronicAcid, which C function you are calling? I looked at HDF5 and couldn't find structs used by value in function pointers. For example, [H5Lvisit](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5L.html#Link-Visit) has an argument of type `H5L_iterate_t`, which is a function pointer with arguments  `hid_t, const char *, const H5L_info_t *, void *`. These are all fine: `hid_t` is an alias for `int`, and `H5L_info_t` is a struct but is passed by pointer.

Comment: herr_t H5Literate( hid_t group_id, H5_index_t index_type, H5_iter_order_t order, hsize_t *idx, H5L_iterate_t op, void *op_data )

Comment: So basically, what you were mentioning. Last time I worked on this I was trying to create a C function pointer from a Scheme function with the parameters (int, void*, void*, void*) and I ran into problems from there, because casting from one type of C function pointer to another is undefined. Is it possible to specify specific pointer type in Guile?

Comment: More specifically, how would I go about creating an instance of H5L_iterate_t?

Comment: From a Guile procedure?

Comment: Sorry for the jumbled mess, I am on mobile and leaving a comment is a bit clunky. I want to create a new line, but it just submits the comment instead.

Comment: @MoronicAcid: Use `(procedure->pointer int your_scheme_proc (list int '* '* '*))` to create an instance of `H5L_iterate_t`. The typedef declarations create synonyms, not new types, so following the declarations gives the real type. If it doesn't work, update your question with a minimal complete example. Also, have a look at the qsort example in [Dynamic FFI](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Dynamic-FFI.html), which passes a Scheme procedure to a C function.

Comment: I have already done that, and I get a segmentation fault whenever I try to call my wrapper from Scheme.

Comment: @MoronicAcid I've updated my answer and added a complete example. Feel free to mark this answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it resolves your question.